# How to correctly configure SAML 2.0 SP

Tags: single-sign-on, saml-2.0, kentor-authservices

I have an [Identity Provider](http://channeltivity.com) that I wish to preform SSO against using SAML 2.0 
I'm using https://github.com/KentorIT/authservices
The IdP configuration is :
Entity Id: https://xxx.yyy.com/auth 
Assertion Consumer Service URL: http://zzz:1111/AuthServices/Acs 
I have created a self-signed certificate and added it to the local project.

The local configuartion:

```
<kentor.authServices entityId="https://xxx.yyy.com/Files/Metadata/IdP/Saml"
                       returnUrl="http://localhost:8585/">
    <identityProviders>
      <add entityId="https://xxx.yyy.com/"
           signOnUrl="https://xxx.yyy.com/Saml/Login.aspx"
           allowUnsolicitedAuthnResponse="true" binding="HttpRedirect">
        <signingCertificate fileName="~/App_Data/SelfSignedCertificate-2016-01-10-22-37.cer" />
      </add>
    </identityProviders>
    <federations>
      <add metadataLocation="http://localhost:52071/Federation" allowUnsolicitedAuthnResponse="true" />
    </federations>
  </kentor.authServices>
```

I will appreciate any kind of help as i'm stuck with this.

Thanks
Gilad

Answer (score 1):

- The first `entityId`, in the `kentor.authServices` root element should be the identifier you use for your site. Typically `http://zzz:1111/AuthServices`, which is the ACS url minus the last part.
- The `signingCertificate` within the `identityProviders/add` element should not be your own certificate, but the certificate that the Idp uses to sign messages.
- The `federations` element should be completely removed. It points to the local development environment, that it looks like you've copied the config from.

Comment: Hi Anders , thank you very much for finding the time to answer me. The certificate is from the IdP site. I have downloaded it and added it to the project. I have removed the **federation** section , and rename the **EntityId** as instructed . Still mo luck. I must be doing something wrong with the configuration .

Comment: Please provide any exception messages, that will make debugging much easier.

Comment: Would it be OK to send a personal mail with exact config to understand if the problem is with me or with 3rd party IdP ?  I don't have logs and the IdP support is not that good.

Comment: Sure, drop me a mail and I'll have a look at it.